# Quasar PWA Workbox route exclude

Tags: javascript, routes, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm pretty new to javascript programming, I managed to make a PWA type application, made with Quasar, and now I'm looking for a solution to exclude some routes. I'm trying to exclude for example "/registerWoE" from appearing the install button. My app is purposed to be a B2C app.

- Case 1: If a Client wants to register on the app via path above, provided by an employee I don't want the Install button to appear.
- Case 2: If an Employee access "/admin" path, the Install button can appear and the Employee can install his application in the phone / PC for easier access.

I found that I need to change to "/src-pwa/custom-service-worker.js", but I couldn't figure out how to exclude that path.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this snippet to the pages you want to ignore.

See [beforeinstallprompt on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onbeforeinstallprompt)

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    deferredPrompt = e; // if you want to automate showing it later
});
```

Comment: For that path I was thinking to remove the service-worker.js. for example when I inspect that page, the service worker should not appear in the application tab but on other routes should appears. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

Comment: so would you want to disable the service worker entirely for that page? if all you want to do is hide the install prompt, I think this would be more performant.

Comment: I am trying to exclude because after I'm moving the build in production after I changed some components in that page, the older content still appears for some of the users(I'm thinking because of it's service-worker precache) and I'm trying to avoid users posting the content on obsolete API methods. The only variant I saw is the user must refresh that page repeatedly to bring the new page to appearing correctly.